# How do we make the same input shape of nn.linear() & nn.Conv2d() in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

1. nn.linear(c1, c2)
   input shape example should be [B, H, W, C1]
2. nn.Conv2d(c1, c2)
   input shape example should be [B, c1, H, W]

So, we need to use function like rearrage(x, 'b h w c -> b c h w')
when out of 1) layer should be input of 2) layer.

But, rearrage need lots of computational time.
Is there any chance to effectively reduce computation time??

Answer (score 0):

`torch.permute` returns a view so it won't require computation:

> Returns a view of the original tensor `input` with its dimensions permuted

```
>>> x = x.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
```